# 'AgentsClient' object has no attribute 'set_agent'

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I am trying to make a dialogflow agent using dialogflow python client. I am referring to the documentation provided by google at https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/api.html#dialogflow_v2.AgentsClient.set_agent .

By following the documentation i wrote the following code

```
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/home/ubuntu/myServiceAccountKey.json"
client = dialogflow.AgentsClient()
agent = {"parent": "project-id","displayName":"Agent1","defaultLanguageCode":"en-US","timeZone":"Asia/Kolkata"}
response = client.set_agent(agent)
```

But when i run the above program i got the following error

**AttributeError: 'AgentsClient' object has no attribute 'set_agent'**

Clearly client object has no 'set_agent' attribute. This is the result of dir(client)

```
['SERVICE_ADDRESS', '_INTERFACE_NAME', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_client_info', '_inner_api_calls', '_method_configs', 'enums', 'export_agent', 'from_service_account_file', 'from_service_account_json', 'get_agent', 'import_agent', 'project_path', 'restore_agent', 'search_agents', 'train_agent', 'transport']
```

How can this be possible when google has itself mentioned in its document to use set_agent() function to create or update the agent?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue. Turns out, `set_agent` method has been added at 2019-10-16, but I installed dialogflow library before then. Try update a dialogflow library through pip command on your python environment.

```
pip install --upgrade dialogflow
```